# Will the OpenID information in my profile page be visible to others?

Tags: support

In my profile page I am able to see my openids - and the emails associated with them.

I checked several profiles and I am not able to see their open id information.

Is this because only the users themselves can see their open id information or because, the accounts I checked have all hidden it or something?

P.S. Privacy paranoia is making me asking stupid questions :|

Comment: Use the "Open link in incognito window" or "Private Browsing" mode of your browser to verify what users who are not you will see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only you can see certain stuff in your profile, such as your email, OpenID and real name. The same goes for the votes you've cast.

Comment: Others can see your vote totals.

Comment: @squillman but not individual votes.

Comment: Right, just clarifying.